# Electron desktopCapturer large version of thumbnail

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using desktopCapturer to take and the code below to take a desktop screenshot.

```
takeScreenshot() {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'] })
    .then( (sources: { thumbnail: { toDataURL: () => any; }; }[]) => {
      
      const theimage = sources[0].thumbnail.toDataURL(); // Thumbnail size image


    })
  }
```

My question is: `sources[0].thumbnail.toDataURL()` is very small.

Can it either be made large or is the large version of the image somewhere in sources?

If so where or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass thumbnailSize as a setting to `getSources()`.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer#methods

```
takeScreenshot() {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'], thumbnailSize: { width: 800, height: 600 })
    .then( (sources: { thumbnail: { toDataURL: () => any; }; }[]) => {
      
      const theimage = sources[0].thumbnail.toDataURL(); // Thumbnail size image


    })
}
```